# C++: char* vs char(*)[]

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm new with C++ and came to this problem, here is my code:

```
shared_ptr<char[]>var(new char[20]);

char *varptr = *(var.get());
```

So I'm creating smart pointer of char array.

The problem that I'm having is that during compilation it gives me error saying:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'char(*)[]'
```

As the  declaration of `shared_ptr::get` says `T* get() const noexcept;` it returns the pointer of template, in my case pointer to `char[]`. Dereferencing it should give me the `char[]` and assigning it to `char*` should be ok.

It seems like I'm missing something and can't figure out what.

What is the difference between `char*` and `char(*)[]`? Isn't `char(*)[]` just a pointer of char array? Shouldn't assigning it to `char*` be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char(*)[]` is a pointer to an array (of unknown size) of `char`, it can point to an array.

`char*` is a pointer to a `char`, it can point to an element of an array.

Semantically the two types are *very* different things.

To get a `char *` from a `char(*)[]`, you need to get a pointer to an specific element of the array (typically the first element):

```
char* varptr = &(*var.get())[0];
```

And if all you want is a string, then use `std::string` instead.

---

To explain the difference between pointer to element, and pointer to array, consider the following array:

```
char a[3];
```

A pointer to the first element (`a[0]`) can be expressed as `&a[0]`, which is what plain `a` decays to. A pointer to the whole array is `&a`.

If we show it how it's laid out in memory, with some "pointers" added, it's like this:

```
+------+------+------+-----
| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | ...
+------+------+------+-----
^      ^      ^      ^
|      |      |      |
a      a+1    a+2    |
|                    |
&a                   (&a)+1
```

Even through the pointers `a` (which is equal to `&a[0]`) and `&a` point to the same location, they are two different pointers and doing pointer arithmetic on them will do different things.

Comment: Thanks. One more question please, pointer of char array and pointer to char aren't the same thing? they both hold the address of same type? why is it problem to assign one to another? sorry if question sounds silly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, only reason why assigning pointer of char array to char pointer is impossible because of the arithmetic operation on them are different?

Comment: @Ojs No the *types* are different. Pointer arithmetic difference is because of the type difference.

Comment: and one more please :) `char(*)[]` is of "type" `&a` right?

Comment: @Ojs The type of `&a` (in my example) is really `char(*)[3]`. In your question the type is `char(*)[]` (with an indeterminate size) because the smart pointer doesn't know the size.

Comment: Thank you very much for brief explanations